# MVC - is there a way to declare multiple properties in a model with the same attributes, different names

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I need to declare a lot of properties of a model that all have the same attributes. I was wondering if there was any way to do this in MVC.

```
[Required]
[Range(0, 4, ErrorMessage = "Integrity is required.")]
public int Integrity { get; set; }

[Required]
[Range(0, 4, ErrorMessage = "Empathy is required.")]
public int Empathy { get; set; }
```

I have a bunch of fields that use those 2 attributes (required and range), The only thing differing is the name of the properties. Is there any way to declare these in a way that involves less repetition?

Comment: You can create your Custom Attribute using ValidationAttribute class and overwrite its IsValid() method. and here you can write all required logic for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no any built-in feature for your requirement however you can achieve this functionality using ModelValidatorProviders. You have to create your own provider and pass it to MVC. 
Create your own attribute which will accept type of annotation as well as array of properties to which it should get applied. and then you can write required logic inside that attribute accordingly.
Have a look at this link it will surely give you hint how to get this done..

**[CustomModelValidatorProvider](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/541244/Conditional-ASP-NET-MVC-Validation-using-Data-Anno)**